# My GPU - What is the exact model? It is working? Is it integrated?

Tags: amd-graphics, amdgpu, integrated

The title is the full description of the question. [lspci & neofetch output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4uGBa.png). 
I cant find the exact model of my GPU because the output from `neofetch` shows too many configurations. Which of them is correct?

I followed [this link](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/e4lc0t/what_is_my_gpu_model_amd/). The situation is very similar to that of mine but none of the answers helped.

If you feel to downvote the question, please leave out a comment where I can find additional info on the matter.

`nroot@SP7:/etc/apt$ lspci`

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 08)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (rev 07)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
00:15.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1 (rev 21)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev f1)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f1)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #6 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point LPC Controller/eSPI Controller (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
01:00.0 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Topaz XT [Radeon R7 M260/M265 / M340/M360 / M440/M445 / 530/535 / 620/625 Mobile] (rev c3)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10)
03:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 31)
```

---

`nroot@SP7:/etc/apt$ neofetch`

```
OS: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS x86_64 
Host: 81DE Lenovo ideapad 330-15IKB 
Kernel: 5.4.0-33-generic 
Uptime: 1 hour, 15 mins 
Packages: 1979 (dpkg), 10 (snap) 
Shell: bash 5.0.16 
Resolution: 1920x1080 
DE: GNOME 
WM: Mutter 
WM Theme: Adwaita 
Theme: Yaru-dark [GTK2/3] 
Icons: Flat-Remix-Blue-Dark [GTK2/3] 
Terminal: guake 
CPU: Intel i5-8250U (8) @ 3.400GHz 
GPU: Intel UHD Graphics 620 
GPU: AMD ATI Radeon R7 M260/M265 / M340/M360 / M440/M445 / 530/535 / 620/625 Mobile 
Memory: 2584MiB / 7868MiB
```

EDIT:
`nroot@SP7:/etc/apt$ DRI_PRIME=1 glxinfo | grep OpenGL`

```
OpenGL vendor string: X.Org
OpenGL renderer string: AMD ICELAND (DRM 3.35.0, 5.4.0-33-generic, LLVM 9.0.1)
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.6 (Core Profile) Mesa 20.0.4
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.60
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 4.6 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 20.0.4
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.60
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL profile mask: compatibility profile
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 Mesa 20.0.4
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

Comment: You can see the model in lspci output.

Comment: @Pilot6, in `lspci` output, which is the model? The VGA controller or the Display controller?

Comment: You have two GPUs. One is Intel the other is AMD. You see the same in neofetch.

Comment: Does that mean I have an Hybrid GPU? if that is the case, Which is my exact AMDGPU model? Is my AMDGPU functional as it should be?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. I can't copy text from a picture and write an answer. You can copy text from a terminal. Please [edit] your question. Yes you have hybrid graphics.

Comment: @Pilot6, can you please take a look now? I believe I did what you expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have hybrid graphics.

The integrated GPU is `Intel UHD Graphics 620`.

The discrete GPU is `AMD ATI Radeon R7 M260/M265 / M340/M360 / M440/M445 / 530/535 / 620/625 Mobile`.

You can check if your AMD GPU is working by running

```
DRI_PRIME=1 glxinfo | grep OpenGL
```

According to your output it is an `AMD ICELAND` chip and it works.

It should be `R7 M260`.

Comment: Thanks for taking intrest in the question doing needful edits. Does this mean that I cant really find out the model of my AMDGPU? Like is it M260? M265? M625? Which exactly? correct me if Im wrong.

Comment: It doesn't matter from the system point of view. These are marketing names depending on RAM and some settings. Why does it matter?

Comment: I just wanted to know the model. Thats all. Anyway, Thanks for your time. Sorry if I was asking too many illogical questions.

Comment: Most likely it is `R7 M260`. You can check the code by `lspci -nn | grep Display`. And then try to Google the model.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the part identifying the dedicated graphics card, I had a similar story (on Ubuntu 20.04). However I check it, my system identifies my dedicated graphics card as some variant or subset of the following:

> Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Cape Verde PRO / Venus LE /
> Tropo PRO-L [Radeon HD 8830M / R7 250 / R7 M465X]

It is because the current open source driver, installed automatically with the system, `radeon`, can identify it as such.

But it's just a blanket identification. I think it's like a closest match the driver can assume, based on features and compatibility. With this driver in place, seemingly, this is the closest to what my Linux system can reveal about this card.

However, my Dell laptop has a service tag, and **submitting this service tag on the Dell support website** enables one to download a spreadsheet (actually, CSV file) with the exact list of hardware in the specific device.

This is how I learned that my graphics card, actually, is an `AMD FirePro W5130M`.

Studying the card's technical info [on this website](https://www.techpowerup.com/gpu-specs/firepro-w5130m.c2769), it appears that the open driver has came pretty close with the identification.

However, in possession of the accurate designation, I could figure out that the semi-open, optionally installable `amdgpu-pro` driver has direct stated compatibility with this card; it is sitting in the list:

[image: amdgpu-pro driver compatibility chart]

At this point, I am in the position to start pondering whether to install `amdgpu-pro` in the hopes of higher performance, stability, and/or better handling.