# confusion about internal graphics and installation procedure

Tags: graphics, amd-graphics

upon using `sudo lshw -c video` I obtain the information about the graphics processing units in my system as following:

```
p@prikarsystem:~/Downloads$ sudo lshw -c video
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Skylake GT2 [HD Graphics 520]
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 07
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:128 memory:a0000000-a0ffffff memory:90000000-9fffffff ioport:5000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
  *-display
       description: Display controller
       product: Sun XT [Radeon HD 8670A/8670M/8690M / R5 M330 / M430 / Radeon 520 Mobile]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: 83
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=radeon latency=0
       resources: irq:129 memory:80000000-8fffffff memory:a1000000-a103ffff ioport:3000(size=256) memory:a1040000-a105ffff
```

showing `Skylake GT2 [HD Graphics 520]` from `Intel Corporation`; which this being a `VGA compatible controller` I obtain another option with `Display controller` that says the product name is `Sun XT [Radeon HD 8670A/8670M/8690M / R5 M330 / M430 / Radeon 520 Mobile]`. The former has `physical_ID=2` and the latter, `physical_ID=0`.

I personally do not have much experience with the nitty-gritties with graphics processing units and its interaction with operating systems, but I do remember having decent video specs back when I used windows, but when I'm in Linux now, in many situations a video takes a long time to render. Besides there's a sticker of amd-radeon graphics on my system.

I wish to know which physical device I actually have, in order to proceed to install specificaly its drivers. Explanation and help will be really beneficial.

EDIT:

using linux-installable amd driver of corresponding specifications, I obtain this trouble :

```
sudo apt install -f ./fglrx_15.200-0ubuntu1_amd64_ub_14.01.deb
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'fglrx' instead of './fglrx_15.200-0ubuntu1_amd64_ub_14.01.deb'
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 fglrx : Depends: fglrx-core but it is not installable
         Recommends: fglrx-amdcccle but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

what should I do in order to install what I wish here?

Comment: Hi, would you mind posting your Ubuntu version?  What does `lspci -v | grep VGA -A1`say, if executed in a terminal, copied and added to your question by copy/paste ?

Comment: Please don't put screenshots of the terminal. Copy the text from the terminal and paste it directly into the question. Then format the pasted text as code using the {_} icon above the edit window.

Comment: @user68186 that's not necessary true. If this is a desktop PC, that's generally accurate, but if this is a laptop then it probably has some implementation of hybrid graphics. In that case, OP, configuring hybrid graphics on laptops is often a feature of firmware and can't be controlled by the operating system. Also, neither of these GPUs need any intervention from the end user. So you don't and shouldn't attempt to manually install drivers. AMD and Intel graphics are supported at the kernel level. Trying to install other drivers can cause things to break

Comment: Which Ubuntu version do you use with which display manager? Anyhow, the driver you're trying to install is the FGLRX driver that has lost compatibility with Ubuntu's underlying X-org display manager system many years ago. The last Ubuntu release that was compatible with FGLRX was around 2014. Even in the driver's filename: `fglrx_[ ... ]_ub_14.01.deb` seems to suggest 2014. However I don't know about FGLRX's compatibility with the other available — newly promoted as default — display manager, Wayland though. But you would still need a more recent version. If there is one, at all.

Comment: Furthermore, see the discussion [in the comments here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1435331/how-to-check-if-ubuntu-is-actually-utilizing-my-dedicated-graphics-card/1436442#comment2504332_1436442). To repeat myself, on a laptop with hybrid graphics, I too find it confusing to find reassurance whether my dedicated graphics is being used by the OS at a given time or not. Until someone more capable shows up with an answer, you can read up on [vga_switcheroo](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/gpu/vga-switcheroo.html) and maybe on the significance of the `DRI_PRIME` environment variable.

Comment: Also there is supposed to be a way to give priority to / or suppress one of your graphics stacks in the BIOS menu.

Comment: I don't find any amd settings, or firmware except `amdgpu`; although simple `dpkg --configure -a` throws me

```dpkg: error processing package amdgpu-dkms (--configure):
 installed amdgpu-dkms package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
```

Comment: ```dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of amdgpu:
 amdgpu depends on amdgpu-dkms (= 1:5.6.0.15-1098277); however:
  Package amdgpu-dkms is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package amdgpu (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 fglrx
 amdgpu-dkms
 amdgpu```